# d3.js Faux-3D Arcs - Uncaught typeerror: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, queue, topojson

**the data**:
world-110m.json
places.json

**the code**:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/raw/4686432/world-110m.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fraserxu/d3-map/master/datas/places.json")
    .await(ready);
```

**the source**:
[http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4973620]

**the error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

at the below code:

```
 svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.object(world, world.objects.land))
    .attr("class", "land noclicks")
    .attr("d", path);
```

I have deployed the index.html into IIS and also tried having the json data files in the same place and tried with the below as well:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "world-110m.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "places.json")
    .await(ready);
```

Any suggestions on how this can be overcome would be real help.
Thanks,
K

Comment: Is TopoJson required to be installed on my system?

Comment: The example you linked works for me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had these 2 error messages:

```
d3.v3.min.js:1 GET http://localhost/d/4686432/world-110m.json 404 (Not Found)

main.php:139 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined
at ready (main.php:139)
at y (queue.v1.min.js:1)
at i (queue.v1.min.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (queue.v1.min.js:1)
at Object.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.i (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

This resulted in the rendering of a an empty globe:

[Empty Globe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qahlz.jpg)

I searched online for "world-110m.json" and found this file:

[world-110m.json](https://github.com/d3/d3.github.com/blob/master/world-110m.v1.json)

In my project directory I created a directory "d" and inside of it a directory called "4686432". I created a file "world-110.json" inside "4686432" and copied the code from the previous link into this file.

The globe now renders properly:

[Correctly rendered globe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFdu.jpg)